# jQuery mobile + phonegap(cordova-2.5.0) + Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with history on index.html, if i just use

```
$.mobile.changePage("another.html",{transition:"slide"});
```

on a page like "another.html", everything is ok and I see my html, but if I click on back button it does not work correctly (there will be a index.html with css/style, but i can't use the buttons again etc.).

I tried

```
window.location.href="another.html"
```

This works correctly, but I want to use jquery.

I have a problem only with the history of the index.html. When I use `$.mobile.changePage(...)` but not from index.html everything is ok (history beetwen "another.html" and "another1.html").

It looks like problem with cordova/jquery. On Android it's all ok.